# Android change default launcher on reboot and boot_completed 10 second delay

Tags: android, kiosk, bootcompleted

I created a launcher app that will run in Kiosk mode. But recently and strange  things started happening on some devices. The default launher is reseted after rebooting the device (with or without my app), so it asked users to pick a default launcher after rebooting.

I tried to solve this by implementing a service to kill other running launcher and start my app from background. I start the service upon "BOOT_COMPLETED" is received. It works as I expected except it has a 10 second delay after the keyguard appeared.

Does anyone have the similar problems before and solved successfully? Either the reset default or 10 second delay problem?

Thanks!

Comment: One of the reasons why the system would reset the selected launcher is when the launcher crashes. Without any code and/or logcat, I can't really help you more than that...
The delay of "BOOT_COMPLETED" is normal, it can even be longer on some devices.

Comment: The most frustrated part is that some devices didn't reset the selected launcher but some did

Comment: It's very possible that your program crashes on some devices and not others. Try to get a logcat.

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem of 10 seconds delay ?